# Structuremap can't resolve an instance if it depends on an enum

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap

I have an integration test which initialize a test wcf service host in code.
Recently I integrated Structuremap and wcf, and now the wcf infrastructure uses structuremap to create service instances.
One of the services I host depends on an enum.
The configuration for the service looks like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    MyService(MyEnum enum)
    {
       ...
    }
}

For<MyService>().Use<MyService>().Ctor<MyEnum>().Is(MyEnum.Value);
```

When I try to resolve the service, I get structuremap error 202 (No default instance is registered for plugin family "MyNamespace.MyService")

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Is MyService the implementation?  What is the interface?  If you take the enum out of the constructor and wire it up do you get the same error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just register the type with a factory delegate:

```
For<MyService>().Use(() => new MyService(MyEnum.Value));
```

Comment: This only works if the type is easily initialized, but if the enumeration is just one value of many constructor arguments, this doesn't work.